# python requests SSL:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

Im trying to consume an API using python-requests behind a proxy, but im getting the "SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER" error.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I tried this:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import json

urllib3.disable_warnings()


auth = (<ID>,<APIKEY>)
headers = {    'Content-Type': "application/json",    }

url = "https://api.intsights.com/public/v1/api/version"
version = requests.request("GET", url, auth = auth, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(version.text+"\n")
```

But im getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.intsights.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /public/v1/api/version (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/user1/Desktop/Coding/python/phishing/phishing2.py", line 17, in <module>
version = requests.request("GET", url, auth = auth, headers=headers, verify=False)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.intsights.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /public/v1/api/version (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Comment: Typically this means the server only supports SSL2 and your client only supports SSL3 or the reverse (these days, even TLSv1.3-only servers aren't unheard of). Use `openssl s_client` from a modern version of the openssl command line tools to get a verbose accounting of what the server supports, and look at what version of openssl your Python libraries are linked against.

Comment: This error is typically caused by connecting to a site which does not speak TLS. The site in question should have no problems but there might be some middlebox or firewall in between or a captive portal which intercept the TLS handshake and reply in an unexpected way. Or a wrong proxy configuration.